# ionic - building for web, index.html looking for files that don't exist

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, phonegap

I'm having an issue with Ionic. I've built for iOS and Android in the past and have had no issues.

I now want to host my ionic project on the web, so I'm trying to build and upload the files that it produces to my hosting server.

I build using:

```
ionic build --prod
```

I've also tried:

```
ionic cordova build browser --prod --release
```

I don't get any error messages, so I go to `platforms > browser > www` and I copy the entire folder and upload it to my hosting server. It's about 237 files.

After uploading I try to visit the url that it should be on `https://myurl.com/www/index.html` and I get errors that it's looking for files that just don't exist.

```
index.html:19 GET https://myurl.com/styles.eef8d0b037ae75ae3ee1.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

index.html:23 GET https://myurl.com/runtime-es2015.83b0bcbb60824f9bb8b4.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

index.html:19 GET https://myurl.com/styles.eef8d0b037ae75ae3ee1.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

index.html:23 GET https://myurl.com/main-es2015.002da15914054dfd59d6.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm simply uploading the `www` folder. Should I be uploading something else?

Any advice would be great. Thank you.

Comment: so after using "ionic build --prod" you should see 'www' folder in your root folder. Try downloading a simple http local server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server and run it in this folder to see if it works.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko ah I see, is the `www` in the root folder the folder I should be uploading?

Comment: yep. You could also build and use the platform browser folder but it is easier to copy your root www

Comment: @SergeyRudenko that didn't work either. I still get the same error messages highlighted above

Comment: i see, so your site url has www as a folder for index.html, can you share more details about how you upload your www folder? your index.html most likely points at root (see baseUrl there) hence the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are uploading your web files to a 'www' folder of your hosting:

https://myurl.com/www/index.html <-- note 'www' here.

While your index.html most likely points at the base url being the root of your domain (404 errors saying there is no such a file etc). Your index.hml will by default has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>

  <base href="/" />
...
</head>
```

So to fix this issue you need to either:

- upload the files without www folder
- change base href to point at www (see this doc: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)